# Repeating calculation with different DF

Tags: r

I have around 10 DFs and would like to perform the following calculations on all of them and then have out as 10 new DFs.

I have been able to get this to work for 1 DF, but rather than copying the code and changing the names, 10 times, I wanted to see if there is a way to do this in. Ideally, I end up with 1 DF and 10 different columns, but am happy with anything

The calculations I am trying to do are:

```
temp <- merge (x=DF1, y=temp1, by = c("name"), all.x= TRUE) 
asset_column <-grep("^Assets_", names(DF1))
return_column <-grep("^Return_", names(DF1))
OutputDF <- 
     stack(colSums(t(t(temp[asset_column])/colSums(temp[asset_column], 
      na.rm=TRUE)) * US_only[return_column],na.rm =TRUE))
OutputDF['values'] = OutputDF['values']/100
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: Put the 10 dataframes in a list, write a little function for the task to be done and use `lapply()`.

Answer (score 2):

If these are repeatable calculations in a `list`, loop through the `list` with `lapply` and do the same code where we specify the first dataset from the anonymous function call (`function(x) x`)

```
out <- lapply(lst1, function(x)  {
       temp <- merge (x, y=temp1, by = c("name"), all.x= TRUE)

        asset_column <-grep("^Assets_", names(x))
        return_column <-grep("^Return_", names(x))
      OutputDF <- 
 stack(colSums(t(t(temp[asset_column])/colSums(temp[asset_column], 
  na.rm=TRUE)) * US_only[return_column],na.rm =TRUE))
  OutputDF['values'] = OutputDF['values']/100
  OutputDF
})
```

Here, the output is also a `list` of `data.frame`s which can be kept in the `list` as such or extract with `[[`